# Where to store java stream helper methods

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Where is preferred place to store functions for improve readibility of streams?

For example:

```
private BinaryOperator<Cash> sumPayments() {
    return (payment1, payment2) -> payment1.sum(payment2);
}
```

I'm not sure if it should be in service class where it's used, but maybe it will be in many places so whats about some extra static Utils? or in entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where possible avoid unnecessary helper methods.

In this particular example, the helper method can easily be replaced with a method reference, which is (arguably *more*) readable:

```
Cash total = subtotals.stream().reduce(Cash.ZERO, Cash::sum);
```

In other cases, where you actually do need a helper: think about where you would search for such a helper method in a year, when you have to adapt your now-barely-familiar code to new requirements.

- Is it more entity related? Put it in the entity class
- Is it more business logic related? Put it into the business logic
- Is it generally useful? Put it into a utility class

Comment: Yes in this situation method reference is enough

Comment: To the second part in this example i think that best place is in entity class, but i was scared of make it too big and littered

Comment: @AlexCurvers it does nothing usefull (certainly not summing up 2 values), but it compiles